# Issue using DATE_FORMAT in inline SQL query Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, sql, date, flask

My query is as below in python flask

```
result = app._engine.execute ("select bookingid, DATE_FORMAT(bookingdate, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(pickupdate, '%Y-%m-%d'), consigneeid, fromcity from booking where consignerid = '{0}'".format(loginid))
```

This query works when I run in MySQL Workbench and returns date in format yyyy-mm-dd but when I run that in python flask get the below error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

It's looking for more arguments though the % in the query is for formatting and not for passing arguments. I did try searching for the reason but couldn't find a good one, what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using MySQL Connector for Python you should escape literal %, this is because Python uses the percent sign (%) for string formatting.

try this:

```
result = app._engine.execute ("select bookingid, DATE_FORMAT(bookingdate, '%%Y-%%m-%%d'), DATE_FORMAT(pickupdate, '%%Y-%%m-%%d'), consigneeid, fromcity from booking where consignerid = '{0}'".format(loginid))
```

Comment: Thanks Occasus for pointing out the escape character %, was trying with backslash, the query you provided works perfectly, to make it render in bootstrap table, I added 'as bookingdate' i.e. DATE_FORMAT(bookingdate, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') as bookingdate, rest all good.

Comment: I have tried this.  I have %s for formatting date seconds, however this is also the replace string for queries using params.  I then get the error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement.  Double %% did not work in this case.